# Nesting Twig imports for modular macro organization

Tags: twig

I'd like to break up a collection of Twig macros into individual files, then import them using a library file to collect all the import statements.

Currently all our macros are in one file, but I'd rather see something like this:

**macro/hello.twig**:

```
{% macro hello() %}
    Hello
{% endmacro %}
```

**macro/goodbye.twig**:

```
{% macro goodbye() %}
    Goodbye
{% endmacro %}
```

**macro_lib.twig**:

```
{% import "macro/hello.twig" as hello %}
{% import "macro/goodbye.twig" as goodbye %}
```

The base template should just import `macro_lib.twig`, but this doesn't work:

```
{% import "macro_lib.twig" as lib %}
{{ lib.hello.hello() }}
```

But trying to call the nested macro returns `Fatal error: Call to undefined method __TwigTemplate_d7...30::gethello()`

I also tried namespaced imports like `{% from "macro/hello.twig" import hello as hello %}` but those also failed.

Is it possible to nest imported macros like this?

Comment: Hello, I'm facing the same problem today… did you finally end up with a (solid) solution ? I tried using _self but it did not help .. `:(`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need define macro in `macro_lib.twig` as

```
{% macro lib() %}
   {% import "macro/hello.twig" as hello %}
   {% import "macro/goodbye.twig" as goodbye %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Then you will be able to call sub macros

```
{% import "macro_lib.twig" as lib %}
{{ lib.hello.hello() }}
```

Because the `macro_lib.twig` you have is just a container of sub macros and you need to define a macro inside to be able to use it

Comment: This isn't working, I'm still getting the fatal `undefined method` error looking for `gethello()`